# Set and execute a command from a function

Tags: fish

How can I write a fish function that executes a command in a string and make it appear in the history?

```
function qh --description 'Use peco to query command history'
    if test (count $argv) = 0
        set peco_flags --layout=bottom-up
    else
        set peco_flags --layout=bottom-up --query "$argv"
    end

    history | peco $peco_flags | read cmd

    if test $cmd
        commandline $cmd
    else
        commandline ''
    end
end
```

This does not work...

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create a key binding which sets the command line and then executes it; that command will then appear in history. Example:

```
function whatday
    commandline "echo Today is $(date +%A)"
    commandline -f execute
end
bind \eq whatday
```

now alt-q will set the commandline to `echo Today is Sunday` and execute it; it appears in history.

Beyond that there are also [abbreviations](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/interactive.html#abbreviations) which allow replacing tokens with text; but the text is just static (e.g. `gco -> git checkout`).

There is as yet no way for an arbitrary fish function (e.g. run as part of a shell script) to append to history, only delete and read from it.

Comment: It seems it would be more correct to say, "There is *no longer any way*" since `commandline -a ls; commandline -f repaint; commandline -f execute` worked both interactively and via arbitrary function prior to 3.4, even if it was, as [faho calls it](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8807#issuecomment-1070798516) "by accident."